# Can't store multipule object in array using mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this

```
{name :string,
 Answers : [{
content:string,
choice:[string]}]
}
```

In my request I have a json

```
{"name":"fooo",

"answers":[{ 

"content" :"hi",

"choice":["1","2","3"]},

{content":"hello",

 "choice ":["0","25","3"]}
           }]
```

I don't  know how I can store the data of the "answers" array  in mongodb
because  when I do

```
 Const test =new Test({

name:req.body.name,

answers:[{

 content :req.body.answers.content,

choice:req.body.answers.choise

}
]})
```

That throw me a  error  of content  is required  but when  I send a post request white one answer it work and store in data base

Comment: Looks like answers is spelled with a capital letter

Answer (score 1):

Your Request body have `answers` as array

```
{
    "name":"fooo",
    "answers":[
        { "content" :"hi", "choice":["1","2","3"] },
        { "content":"hello", choice ":["0","25","3"] }
    ]
}
```

you have to access array value using the index like `req.body.answers[0].content`

---

Here you can directly use `answers: req.body.answers` which will point your request body answers array.